# Mod rewrite regex

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to rewrite any url like doc/name_of_doc-doc to doc/name_of_doc and pass it to php

```
RewriteRule ^([0-9a-zA-Z\-\_]+)$ /doc/index.php?doc=$1
```

this works fine

I'm trying to deal with the fact that name_of_doc-doc could have a dot as well like name_of.doc-doc

If i go

```
RewriteRule ^([0-9a-zA-Z\-\_\.]+)$ /doc/index.php?doc=$1
```

It has to have - and _ and . 
How to have one OR another ? Like a dot or a dash ? What if i don't have digits ?

Thanks

Comment: Are you missing something after the character class? Like, `*` or `+`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why you need it? Anyway, the simplest way is to duplicate rules:

```
RewriteRule ^([0-9a-zA-Z\.]+)$ /doc/index.php?doc=$1
RewriteRule ^([0-9a-zA-Z\_]+)$ /doc/index.php?doc=$1
```

Or, one rule but harder to read:

```
RewriteRule ^(([0-9a-zA-Z\.]+)|([0-9a-zA-Z\_]+))$ /doc/index.php?doc=$1
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm surprised your regex works at all. By the look of it it should only work if the filename is exactly one character long... Add a `+` after the `]` to fix that.

That might fix your other bug too, since you're doing it fine.

Side-note, use `[0-9a-zA-Z._-]` so you don't have to escape anything (`_` has no special meaning, `.` loses its meaning in a character class, and `-` has no meaning if it's the first or last character of a class)

Comment: I had the +, my mistake. But  ^([0-9a-zA-Z._-]+)$ isn't working with my.saved_DOC-today